# ReactJS Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn reactjs by making some simple apps. I thought I had figured the basics out, until I stumbled upon a situation where I use .bind. I am trying to make a small list that, when clicked, will remove the clicked list-item. The logic behind it is not implemented yet as I keep running into the same error. I have looked through other questions, but for some reason I haven't managed to make it work, so if this is reposted I am sorry.

```
"Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"
```

The code in question is implemented below. I would really appreciate some help on this. I know it's a really basic problem, but hey. Can't always be perfect.

```js
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var dataList = ["Apples","Bananas", "Oranges", "Pinapple"];

var Wrapper = React.createClass({
 handleClick: function(item, event) {
  console.log("clicked");
 },
 render: function() {
  var allData = this.props.datalist;
  return(
   <div>
    <ul>
     {allData.map(function(listpoint,i) {
      return(
       <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,listpoint)} key={"list" + i}>{listpoint} [{i}]</li>
      );
     })}
    </ul>
   </div>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Wrapper datalist={dataList}/>,
 document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `this` for `.map`, because `this` in `.map` callback does not refer to `Wrapper`, it refers to global scope(in browser it is window) or if you use strict mode it will be `undefined`

```
allData.map(function(listpoint,i) {
  return <li 
    onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,listpoint)} 
    key={"list" + i}>{listpoint} [{i}]</li>;
}, this);
__^^^^^^
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/27869/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.

Comment: This also works for _.map(items, iteratee function, this)