# How to get value from <li> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm a beginner in React.js and need some help.
I want to get the value or data from a `<li>`-tag when you click on it. How can I do that?

```
...
clickOnMe : function () {
   this.setState({myData : event.target.value});
}

render : function (){
   return (
   <div>
     <ul>
        <li value="Point" onClick={this.clickOnMe}>Point</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 );
}
...
```

Comment: Do you want to have access to property that is under your control (so you can put it in props or state, or make const), or it's from DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because `target.value` is only used for form elements such as `input`.

You can pass the function a unique identifier, which you then can use to fetch it's value from `this.state`.

Implementations may vary a lot. The biggest question would probably depend on whether or not the value of this element can change in the DOM, or if will remain static at all times.

Here are my proposed solutions for both:

---

### Element can change value in DOM:

If you want to update the value of your `li` element, you can do this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    data: ["point1", "point2", "point3"];
  };
}

clickOnMe = (id) => {
   console.log(this.state.data[id]);
}

changeData = (id, value) => {
   let temp = this.state.data.slice();
   temp[id] = value;
   this.setState({temp});
}

render = () => {
   return (
   <div>
     <ul>
        <li value={this.state.data[0]} onClick={this.clickOnMe.bind(this, 0)}>Point</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 );
}
```

`this.state.data` is an array that is in the components constructor and contains the initial values for each element. When you click on an element, you'd call the `clickOnMe` function and pass in a parameter that corresponds to the index in the array in which the data for the current element is.

If you want to change this value later, you can call `changeData` with the value and index as parameters. Make a copy of the entire array, change the value in said index, then update the `state`.

---

### Element is static in DOM:

If the value of `li` is always static, then you can do:

```
clickOnMe = (val) => {
   this.setState({myData : val});
}

render = () => {
   return (
   <div>
     <ul>
        <li onClick={this.clickOnMe.bind(this, "Point")}>Point</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 );
}
```

If you want things to be static, things are much simpler. Here you can just directly bind which value corresponds to said element, and then in the function do what you want with it.

Comment: I'll try it, and console shows me "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: Thanks for help, I found solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842092/reactjs-cannot-read-property-bind-of-undefined

Comment: @EarlMegget, I have updated the answer above with a better solution to the `bind` error you had. (ES6)

Comment: Bind() in render method will return new function on each render. So reference wiil be new each time and react have to update DOM

Comment: @AlexShwarc, it will return a new function, yes, but it won't trigger an extra update to the DOM unless the new function is passed down to another component.

Comment: Any prove link?

Comment: @AlexShwarc, no. The only thing that triggers a re-render in react is when you update `state` or `props`. So in my first example above, if `this.state.data` was updated, then you would only have 1 update to the DOM because the `state` changed. The `bind` will have a new function but this won't make a second re-render.

Comment: @Chris I agree with props ans state, but you did not understand me. Yes "internal" virtual rendering (calling render() method) will occur when state or props or context changed. But REAL DOM update occurs a bit later, after react reconcilation process, during  which react compares virtual DOM representation and actual DOM. If you use onClick=(e => ,,,) each time virual rendering gives another tree and real browser DOM will be updated without any needs. And bind() is the same.