# unexpected value - e.target.value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am writing the following onclick handler:

```
    changeDate = (e) => {
  console.log("e.target: ",e.target)
  console.log("e.target.value: ", e.target.value)
  // this.setState({date_string : e.target.value})
}
```

for these list items:

```
        let dayList = <ul></ul>

    dayList = this.state.days.map( (el) =>
        <li
            key = {el.toString()}
            onClick = {this.state.loading ? null : this.changeDate}
            value={el}>{el}
        </li>
    )
```

When running my react app, I get the following output from the above console logs:

```
e.target:  <li value=​"2020-01-26">​2020-01-26​</li>​ 
e.target.value:  2020
```

Why is the logged value not the same value displayed in the list object? Various combinations of toString() etc do not appear to help.

Comment: What does `console.log() says?`

Comment: `value` is not a valid attribute/property for `li` elements. Only for form control elements. I'm surprised it lets you add it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `value={el}` and use **innerText** in the handler function

```
e.target.innerText
```

Try the in-text demo:

```js
const App = () => {
const changeDate = e => {
  console.log("e.target: ", e.target);
  console.log("e.target.value: ", e.target.value);
  console.log("e.target.innerText: ", e.target.innerText);
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    <li onClick={changeDate}>{"test"}</li>
  </div>
);
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You're getting undefined because target.value is only used for form elements such as input.

One solution would be to use the `innerText` property as suggested by @keikai above

See this for an insightful answer: [How to get value from li tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737716/how-to-get-value-from-li-tag://)